# Redirecting category links from old to new in wordpress with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Can anyone please tell me why this redirect is not working.
I would like to use my htaccess file to redirect bulk links in wordpress.

For Example.

I would like to redirect the link 
`example.com/category/the-random/art/` to `example.com/category/random-pics/art-pictures/`

additionally I would like to  redirect all of the pages in that category too.
`example.com/category/the-random/art/page/2/` to `example.com/category/random-pics/art-pictures/page/2/`

`example.com/category/the-random/art/page/3/` to `example.com/category/random-pics/art-pictures/page/3/` and so on...

Here is my htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(category)/the-random/art$ /category/random-pics/art-pictures/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(category)/the-random/art/page(/.*)? $1/category/random-pics/art-pictures/page/$2 [L,NC,R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Paul, what error you are getting with your current setup, 404?

Comment: yes when it doesnt find the page it gives a 404 error